# Patterns in php preg replace function

Tags: php

My question is about patterns in a, say, preg_replace function , what i would like to know is how are those patterns created ? for example in the following

```
  $email = preg_replace('|(<a class="magnify".*<\/a>)+|', '', $email);
```

What does the | mean , what does the  + mean ? can you provide me some links on how to create those patterns and what options are to be used ?

Not that easy to find any official docs on the net . 
Thank you

Comment: The "patterns" are called *regular expressions*.  Here's a site with lots of good info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expressions.htm and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expression.htm

Comment: And on the PHP website: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: `+` means match preceding pattern 1 or more times. You would be better of going through a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Regex.

This should help you out - http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers.